# Инициализация массива объектов при передачи в параметр функции

Tags: c#

Возможно ли инициализировать массив в параметре функции? Может есть какие - то "читы" по этому поводу, например лямда функциями или специальными операторами, может новые стандарты `С#` это позволяют? `Params` не подходит!!! p.s. Перешел на `C#` c `C++`

Пример:

```
class Object{}

void getParam(Object[] obj){...}

static main()
{
  //нужно так
  Object[] obj = { new Object()};
  getParam(obj);
  //хочется так:
  getParam(new Object());
  //или так
  getParam({new Object(), new Object()});
}
```

Comment: Вы пишете про новые стандарты C#, значит готовы применить все новые фичи языка. Но в обсуждении в комментариях выясняется, что вы завязаны на старую версию. То есть не готовы применить новые фичи. Где логика?

Comment: @Alexander Petrov вы как - то возбуждены сильно, попейте успокоительного, я знаю что это не вы мне минус поставили, я не вам хотел написать об этом, а когда увидел, сообщение нельзя редактировать было. По поводу новых фишек в новых стандартах - мне интересно в общем узнать было. Проблемы со старой версий dx исправил, перенес на sharpDX

Comment: А вот теперь минус от меня.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov максимум что ты можешь сделать по жизни), таких как ты неадекватов, которые якобы с короной на голове, типо самые умные, ЧСВ в "простонароде", развелось на стэке очень много к сожалению, вместо того чтобы помочь чем-то, начинают ставить себя выше других, если ты задашь вопрос, как-то по их мнению не корректно или где-то ошибся... Короче на этот сайт почти перестал заходить в последнее время и кстати не один я заметил такое поведение ЧСВшников. p.s. накапай модератору, чтобы он почистил оскорбляющий тебя комментарий))), ну или что ты там можешь максимум сделать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, перечитайте свой собственный вопрос. Вы пишете: "Params не подходит" - почему не подходит? Поймите же, что комментарии к чужому ответу никто не будет читать. Отредактируйте вопрос, опишите причину. Упомяните про старую версию фреймворка. Тогда вопрос станет нормальным. Сейчас он - плохой. Он не соответствует правилам оформления, принятым на сайте.

Comment: Обычно такие как вы, бегут жаловаться. Потому что я не стесняюсь в крепких выражениях. И да, я уже близок к тому, чтобы уйти с ресурса из-за таких как вы. Я единственный, кто пытался вам помочь (кроме автора ответа), задавал уточняющие вопросы. И я же в итоге виноват. Ну да, ваши мысли прочитать не смог.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, пользователь, например, Pavel Popov ответил сразу, без лишних вопросов, в нормальном тоне, предложил еще варианты, а у вас - почему???почему???почему??? как будто меня отчитывают перед начальством за не выполненную работу! Это не красиво, если кажется, что вопрос не соответствует правилам, просто пройдите мимо, проигнорируйте, сэкономите свои нервы и "задающего вопрос".

Comment: Stackoverflow - не форум для общения, а база знаний, сайт типа "Вопрос - Ответ". Поэтому здесь вопрос должен соответствовать определённым правилам. И ответы тоже. Ваш вопрос не полностью соответствует правилам, в нём не хватает точной информации. Поэтому вполне естественно, что я стал уточнять эту информацию. На en.so, кстати, делают также.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно такой способ применяют `getParam(new[] {new object()});`

Но можете попробуйте params, тут есть ряд огранчиений, почитайте. Но для вашего примера подходит

```
void getParam(params Object[] obj){...} 

getParam(new Object(), new Object());
```

Comment: спс, за ответ, но params - точно не подходит!

Comment: @Duracell а так ?) getParam(new[] {new object()});  еще короче я не знаю

Comment: Нет, нельзя вставлять params в параметры функции, оно накладывает огромные ограничения на работоспособность моей функции

Comment: @Duracell так это пример без params  getParam(new[] {new object(),new object()});

Comment: Извините, не увидел, сейчас проверю

Comment: Проверил, не работает, за попытку помочь, спс.

Comment: @Duracell - почему `params` не подходит?

Comment: @Alexander Petrov приходится парсить лист массивов, и порядок агрументов приходится менять, не удобно очень, но признаю метод хороший

Comment: @Duracell - то есть в сигнатуре `getParam` есть и другие параметры? Почему это не указано в вопросе?

Comment: @Alexander Petrov не думал что это важно, привел простейший пример

Comment: @Duracell Не работает в каком смысле ? не компилится или не подходит по иной причине ? какая версия .NET Framework ?

Comment: @Павел Попов да, вы правы, скорее всего не компилиться, из-за версии 3.5

Comment: @Duracell а ну тогда понятно ) не у верен, что заведется на версии 4.5, но на 4.7.2 точно работает. А почему такая древняя версия ? если нужно под XP, там 4.5 на сервис-пак 2 на сколько помню заводится

Comment: @Павел Попов Да, нужна поддержка XP ((( , попробую на 4.5 завести

Comment: @Duracell сочувствую :-) У меня то же есть такое легаси...больше всего страдаю от отсутствия  async/await и все таки я ошибся, увы с версии 4 поддержка https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/get-started/system-requirements

Comment: @Павел Попов приходится сидеть на 3.5 потому что не могу прилепить directX9 на платформу выше чем 3.5, он просто не рисует окне(((

Comment: @Alexander Petrov за что минус поставили?

Comment: @Duracell - зачем вы врёте? Про минус от меня.

Comment: Почему важная информация: наличие других параметров, вынужденная привязанность к версии фрейморка - не написана прямо в вопросе? Почему её приходится узнавать в комментариях (которые никто не читает)?

Comment: Обоим: вы в курсе, что вполне можно использовать новую версию языка со старой версией фреймворка? Только ради всего святого, не спрашивайте, как это сделать, в комментариях - создайте новую тему с вопросом, если понадобится